# Changing font of the titlepage of tufte-book

Tags: tufte

I would like to change the font and the style used in the titlepage of `tufte-book` class.

I don't like the 'all caps' style and would rather have normal text in that page.

By reading the documentation I have found only the commands for changing fonts in other elements, such as captions, but not in the title page. In the attempts I made I was able to modify the style of the title, but other elements (like the author name) stay all caps.

This is the basic code I am using:

```
\title[Sample title]{%
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
    Sample \par% 
    Title \par \vspace{1cm}
    }
%   \usebox{\titleimage}}


\author{Author name here}
```

which produces this page:

[image]

Is there anyone who knows how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add a simple example of how you're producing the title page? Having some code to play with is better.

Comment: I modified the question and added the code + output. I removed the graphics (`\titleimage`) for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To redesign the title page, just redefine the `\maketitlepage` macro:

```
\renewcommand{\maketitlepage}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  {%
  \sffamily
  \begin{fullwidth}%
  \fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\thanklessauthor}%
  \vspace{11.5pc}%
  \fontsize{36}{40}\selectfont\par\noindent\textcolor{darkgray}{\thanklesstitle}%
  \vfill
  \fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont\par\noindent\thanklesspublisher%
  \end{fullwidth}%
  }%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \clearpage
}
```

Here I've removed the original `\allcaps` formatting.

Comment: For this to work I needed to convince LaTeX to let me redefine the macro. I added `\let\maketitlepage\relax` right before the `\newcommand`.

Comment: @m00am Whoops! Good catch! I've updated the answer to use `\renewcommand`.

Comment: Ah, that is shorter and less ugly than my attempt. Thank you for this answer (and for tufte-latex :) ).

Answer (score 1):

The `tufte-book` class sets the title and the author using `\allcaps`.  You can just `\let\allcaps=\relax` for the titlepage.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\title[Sample title]{%
  Sample%
  \par\noindent
  Title
}
\author{Author name here}
\begin{document}
{
  \let\allcaps=\relax
  \maketitle
}
\end{document}
```

> [image]